# Reboot and select proper boot device error after changing partition table

Tags: linux, windows, bios

I have a problem with starting installation of Windows from a pendrive onto my [Samsung NP700G7C-S01](http://www.samsung.com/de/support/model/NP700G7C-S01DE) laptop. Here are things which I did:

1. I formatted all disks on my laptop via [GParted](http://gparted.org) from Ubuntu on a USB pen drive.
2. Then I ran Windows installation from the USB pen drive, but I got an error message saying that partition table for Window should be GPT instead of MBR so I change partition table on all disks via following operations for all disks:

   ```
   select disk #
   clean
   convert gpt
   ```

But after this when I restarted my laptop I got following error:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected
>   Boot device and press any key.

I tried resetting boot options to default, disabling fast BIOS, changing BIOS priority but nothing helps me so I don’t have any idea what I should do next.

Is the only option to obtain results, is to plug in another disk and then switch partition table on one of current disks from GPT to MBR, right?

Comment: For UEFI boot, ensure that Legacy mode boot is disabled and check disk order. For more info see [this article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Comment: I check disk order and play with this for example change order of disks etc. but it didn't help. I ensure this. Also I check articles similar to this one but I have one problem ma cd rom doesn't work so this is why I use pendrive to start windows/ubuntu whatever...

Comment: How did you create the pendrive? ([this article](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html) might help).

Comment: I create bootable pendrive via mediacreationtool from microsoft (and I install windows from this about 10 times..) but I will also try this one from article which You post. Maybe this will help me.

Comment: Did this help ?

Comment: @harrymc I'm currently not able to perform what You suggest because of logistics problems, but I think Your answer/comment is the most helpful (I guess)

Comment: I have added it then as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with the creation of the boot pendrive.

See this article :
[How to Create a Bootable UEFI USB Flash Drive for Installing Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html)

On how to :

- Create a Bootable UEFI USB Flash Drive using Free Program [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ)
- Manually Create a Bootable UEFI USB Flash Drive

Answer (score 0):

If installing windows via UEFI boot, it requires GPT partition.  If installing windows via BIOS boot, it requires MBR partition.

Sounds like you initially booted from USB stick via UEFI.

Perhaps you need to watch for a prompt to press F* for boot source selection, or make sure UEFI boot is enabled (by "BIOS" setup)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336946.aspx

Comment: UEFI Boot is enabled and so I get the prompt..

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that when you did a `clean` in diskpart, you accidentally had your USB flash drive selected.

Put it in another computer and check to see if it still has any files on it ;-)

Comment: It has. I made clean on my 3 disks in laptop.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate UEFI partition (ESP)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd799232(v=ws.10).aspx#PartitionStructures

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you've already tried all this and still facing the issue then you should try these other ways too to reboot and select proper boot device in samsung laptops. Here's the link to that article: [Reboot And Select Proper Boot Device In Windows PC](https://www.geekfell.com/reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device/)

Comment: Answers that require the reader to follow a link to get the content are not answers, per the rules of this site. Please edit your post to include the relevant information, making sure it doesn't simply duplicate the information others have already provided.